# Why does c++ app launched from the Netbeans use Netbeans install dir?

Tags: c++, programming, paths, netbeans, g++

When I run a simple application that uses a library, Ogre3D in my case, from NetBeans, it breaks with the following message:

```
Error occurred during execution: InternalErrorException: 
Could not load dynamic library /snap/netbeans/84/usr/local/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL.  
System Error: /snap/netbeans/84/usr/local/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL.so.14.1: 
cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory in DynLib::load at 
/home/fedor/projecten/c++/ogre-14.1.0/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 136)
```

The app can not find a library it needs and it looks like it is appending the search path I gave it (usr/local/lib/OGRE) to the installation path of NetBeans (/snap/netbeans/84).

When I launch the same app without NetBeans, just by clicking on it, it runs fine.

How can I get the app when launched from NetBeans to use the right working directory and search in the propper locations for libs?

*(Using Ubuntu 22.04LTS, NetBeans 19 with g++ version 11.4.0)*

Answer (score 0):

It turned out Snap was the problem. I removed the Netbeans snap installation and downloaded the binary package. That did not present any problems at all.